# Same version of node but different module versions

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, node-modules

I have 2 typescript / node projects, both using the same version of node. However when I use `import * as Crypto from 'crypto';` in each project, they point to two different versions of the crypto module:

[image]  [image]

I'm quite new to node and javascript / typescript and struggling to trying to understand why, hoping someone can enlighten me. My question is: why does `import * as Crypto from 'crypto';` resolve to two different versions of crypto even though the projects are setup to use the same versions (I think!)? What determines which version of a built-in module is used? And how can I resolve this so both use the same?

Here's my setup:

**===Project 1===**

```
node -v
v14.15.2
npm -v
6.14.9
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint \"src/**/*\"",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/firestore": "^4.8.0",
    "@sentry/node": "^5.29.2",
    "@sentry/tracing": "^5.29.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bad-words": "^3.0.4",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.4.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.9.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.8.0",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

**===Project 2===**

```
node -v
v14.15.2
npm -v
6.14.9
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "user-approval",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint \"src/**/*\"",
    "build": "tsc",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@sentry/node": "^5.29.2",
    "@sentry/tracing": "^5.29.2",
    "@slack/bolt": "^2.5.0",
    "@slack/web-api": "^5.14.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.9.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.8.0",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
}
```

Comment: Why do you you think that these two versions are different? Because autocompletion is different? Autocompletion in VSCode depends on code written in the project.

Comment: Yes, when I ctrl-click on the word 'crypto' in the import statement in VSCode, it takes me to a file located in `node-modules/@types/node.crypto.d.ts` - in each project, that file is similar but have different functions, so I'm assuming they are different versions of that module. Can you elaborate on "Autocompletion in VSCode depends on code written in the project"?

Comment: Note that your `tsconfig.json` files say you're using CommonJS modules, but `import * as Crypto from 'crypto';` is ESM, not CommonJS.

Comment: VSCode has some kind of smart ordering in autocompletion. The autocompletion popup changes the content depending on the last element used.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I've updated my images to show the actual files I see in VSCode when I navigate to the crypto module. You can see that they are actually differnet - so I don't think autocompletion this is the issue

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ah okay, this sounds like a missing piece of knowledge I need. I'm sorry I don't know what ESM vs CommonJS, I'm looking it up now...

Comment: You are looking at @types/node. That's not built-in. You can set a version for this dependency in package.json.

Comment: Initially I did try to `npm install crypto` but I got a warning that `crypto@1.0.1: This package is no longer supported. It's now a built-in Node module.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the projects have different versions of the `@types/node` package installed. If you run

```sh
npm update @types/node
```

in each project, it should update each of them to the latest.

I was confused at first because `@types/node` didn't appear in your `package.json` files, but it doesn't even if you install it unless you add `--save-dev`. Even though `npm install` defaults to `--save` normally, apparently not for `@types` packages — which makes sense, they're just a dev dependency, not a runtime dependency.

I'd probably add them as a dev dependency by doing:

```sh
npm install @types/node --save-dev
```

Comment: Thanks, that's resolved the issue. I don't quite understand all of this yet, but you've given me a lot of help and I know what to read up about now!